# Algorithm to iteratively compute the reciprocal of a number

Tags: algorithm

I was reading R.G.Droomey's book How to solve it by Computer and in chapter 3 I found this problem - " Design and implement an algorithm to `iteratively compute the reciprocal of a number`." I am totally confused how to do that as he was teaching before how `to compute the square roots` and then suddenly comes up with this question. What's the co-relation?

And what would be the algorithm for this? Plus why do we need this when we can directly find the reciprocal of a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iteratively computing any function probably asks you to use some numerical analysis method, like Newton-Raphson (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) or binary search.

This method, along with the whole concept of numerical analysis (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) allows you to calculate the root of a function f(x) by approximation without using any given formula for the solution.
As an example, you can calculate the root of f(x) = 5*x^2 + sqrt(x) + ln(x), where it is difficult to find a solution formula.

> Plus why do we need this when we can directly find the reciprocal of a
>   number?

Imagine that you need to calculate the reciprocal of a number in a machine where you cannot calculate a division, but only addition, subtraction and multiplication. How do you do it? You use numerical analysis :)